# VBA change dictionary value

Tags: vba, dictionary, sum

Im trying to change values in a dictionary dynamically. If value exists in dictionary, change that value to dictionary value + new value (incremental).

Im unable to do this however, i get the Run-time error 451: Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object. Can someone help me do a "sumifs" -type of changes to the dictionary?

```
Sub Sumifs()

Dim objDictionary
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim arr As Variant
Dim lr1 As Long
Dim arr2 As Variant
Dim lr2 As Long

With Blad15
        lr1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
        arr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E20:E" & lr1)
        Debug.Print UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print lr1
End With

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    objDictionary.Add Key:=CStr(Cells(i + 19, 5)), Item:=CStr(Cells(i + 19, 5))
Next

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Select

    With Blad6
        lr2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        arr2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B" & lr2 + 1)

    End With

For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If objDictionary.Exists(Cells(i + 1, 2).Value) Then
        objDictionary(Cells(i + 1, 2).Value) = objDictionary.Items(Cells(i + 1, 2)) + Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i + 1, 8).Value 'Error occurs here
    End If

Next


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You are confusing things here... If you are storing data inside arrays, why loop through the sheet instead the array? To change, or in this case, add the values from a key dictionary you need to do this logic `If Dict.Exists(Key) Then Dict(Key) = Dict(Key) + newValue`

Comment: I have keys in 1 sheet and values on two other sheets. I dont know how to add values from two sheets in to one dictionary... do have an example? The dictionary holds just keys, but the two sheets have more values than keys (as in keys are customers and values are several invoices per customer. I want to sum all invoices per customer)

Comment: Could you please provide screens of your sheets?

Comment: edited an example above, basically three sheets with dynamic ranges. Summary has unique customers (as in customers only appear once). On the other two sheets the same customers can appear multiple times (as in multiple invoices and multiple payments). I need to develop a code to check how much did we invoice and how much did they pay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments and the screenshots I understood it like that:

I created a new class module `customer` with the code below

```
Option Explicit

Public customerName As String
Public invoiceAmount As Double
Public cashReceived As Double
```

and then I created a new module with the following code for creating the summary

```
    Sub CreateSummary()

    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Dim rgInvoices As Range

    Set rgInvoices = Worksheets("Invoices sent").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rgInvoices = rgInvoices.Offset(1).Resize(rgInvoices.Rows.Count - 1)

    Dim sngRow As Range
    Dim oneCustomer As customer

    Set dict = New Dictionary
    Dim customerName As String
    Dim amount As Double

    ' Sum up the invoice amount for each single customer
    For Each sngRow In rgInvoices.Rows

        customerName = sngRow.Cells(1, 1).Value
        amount = sngRow.Cells(1, 3).Value

        If dict.Exists(sngRow.Cells(1, 1).Value) Then
            dict(customerName).invoiceAmount = dict(customerName).invoiceAmount + amount
        Else
            Set oneCustomer = New customer
            With oneCustomer
                .customerName = customerName
                .invoiceAmount = amount
            End With
            dict.Add oneCustomer.customerName, oneCustomer
        End If

    Next sngRow



    Dim rgCashReceived As Range
    Set rgCashReceived = Worksheets("Cash received").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rgCashReceived = rgCashReceived.Offset(1).Resize(rgCashReceived.Rows.Count - 1)


    ' Sum up the cash received for each single customer
    For Each sngRow In rgCashReceived.Rows

        customerName = sngRow.Cells(1, 1).Value
        amount = sngRow.Cells(1, 3).Value


        If dict.Exists(sngRow.Cells(1, 1).Value) Then
            dict(customerName).cashReceived = dict(customerName).cashReceived + amount
        Else
            Set oneCustomer = New customer
            With oneCustomer
                .customerName = customerName
                .cashReceived = amount
            End With
            dict.Add oneCustomer.customerName, oneCustomer
        End If

    Next sngRow

    ' Print Out
    Dim vKey As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim shOut As Worksheet
    Set shOut = Worksheets("Summary")


    ' Heading
    With shOut
        .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Clear
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Customer Name"
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Invocie amount"
        .Cells(1, 3).Value = "Cash received"

        ' single rows
        i = 2
        For Each vKey In dict.Keys
            Debug.Print vKey, dict(vKey).invoiceAmount, dict(vKey).cashReceived
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = vKey
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = dict(vKey).invoiceAmount
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = dict(vKey).cashReceived
            i = i + 1
        Next vKey

    End With

End Sub
```

**Resolution for Compile error**: User defined type not defined underlining `Dim dict As dictionary` Select Tools->Reference from the Visual Basic menu. Place a check in the box beside “Microsoft Scripting Runtime”

Though question remains: Why don't you use excel's built in SUMIF?

You can also try the second example from [Macromastery](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#A_Real_World_Dictionary_Example)

Comment: Trying the code out but it puts an error at start "Compile error" User defined type not defined, after that it underlines dict As dictionary. Im not using sumif or excel's built in formulas because this is part of a larger set of modules and procedures and is being used by users that are not too familiar with excel.

Comment: You have to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime. I updated the answer.

Comment: Outstanding, thank you!! I was able to put this to the actual context and it produces the wanted result at a great speed. I need to check the logic behind the CurrentRegion choice, as this is new to me, ive previously worked with xldown etc... 

The code does have 1 thing though, i think it excecutes the code twice? As in after the last line has been executed, it returns to the start and does it again. What might be the cause for this?

Either way, outstanding. Ill try to add "invoice counters" to this, such as "how many invoices per customer" but this will work as an example!!

Comment: No idea why it should run twice without knowing the context. In my test case I built it runs only once.

Comment: @Carlsberg789 Told ya dictionaries were awesome ;)